# plt.figure() with title gives error: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem when running the following simple example code on python 2.6.5.
I have looked other solutions to invalid literal problems and it seems to me that this generally occurs when python assumes that the data it is plotting are integers and tries to iterate over the data. However this error seems to be reached before this point, when the figure object is created. I may be wrong about this and would appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
y=np.sin(x)
fig = plt.figure('test figure')
sub1=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
sub1.plot(x,y)
```

Generates the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\u999999\Desktop\code\simple_example.py", line 7, in <module>
fig = plt.figure('test figure')
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 241, in figure
num = int(num)  # crude validation of num argument
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'test figure'
```

***Added from comments***

I'm using matplotlib version 0.99.3rc1

Comment: This is odd. The [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure) say that `figure` can take a string which sets the window title, but apparently, your version only accepts numbers (which seem to be some sort of unique window ID). Maybe you have an old version (haven't checked old docs, though)?

Comment: It works with either an integer or left blank. The code was originally developed on 2.7 but we now have to deploy it on 2.6.5. I will have to investigate the change between versions.

Comment: It's more likely that the *matplotlib* versions are different - Python version shouldn't matter much

Comment: Error in your example: `y=np.sin(x,y)` should be `y=np.sin(x)`

Comment: Yes you are right, thank you. Fixed the typo.

Comment: What version of matplotlib do you use?

Comment: I just checked and I used matplotlib version 0.99.3rc1

Comment: @RobertChristie - Matplotlib `0.99` is very outdated at this point (6 year old release). Setting the window title with `plt.figure("title string")` has been added more recently than that (not sure exactly when, off the top of my head).

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you are trying to access is passing in [a text label as `num`](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.3/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure). Originally you could only put a figure number here, now you can put in a number or string label.

This functionality has been available since [this commit](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/2910319053566f33284c4e5954e2837799d3d643) in June 2011.  The first release version this was in is [version 1.1.0](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v1.1.0/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L317).  You say you're on version 0.99.3rc2 - so the feature won't be available.  My best advice is to upgrade from that (pretty old!) version unless there's a very strong reason not to.

---

#### Details

The line of code that enables you to pass a string in place of an integer figure number  is [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L482), short block of code reproduced below to illuminate the point - the first argument to `matplotlib.pyplot.figure()` is named `num` and defaults to `None`:

```
#snippet from matplotlib.pyplot.figure()

if num is None:
    num = next_num
elif is_string_like(num):
    figLabel = num
    allLabels = get_figlabels()
    if figLabel not in allLabels:
        if figLabel == 'all':
            warnings.warn("close('all') closes all existing figures")
        num = next_num
    else:
        inum = allLabels.index(figLabel)
        num = allnums[inum]
```